# Flutter : How to access states and controllers of pre-made widget that have already been defined by other people

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey listViewKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //listViewKey.currentState.

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: ElevatedButton( //Outer button
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: Size(
                    300.0,
                    100.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text('top'),
                onPressed: () {
                  //What should I do?
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CustomListView(
                key: listViewKey,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomListView> createState() => _CustomListViewState();
}

class _CustomListViewState extends State<CustomListView> {
  late final ScrollController ctrl;
  double position = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    ctrl = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        print(ctrl.offset);
        setState((){
          position = ctrl.offset;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            position.toString(),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            controller: ctrl,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 500.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 500.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 500.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              ElevatedButton( // Inner button
                onPressed: () async {
                  ctrl.animateTo(
                    0.0,
                    duration: Duration(
                      seconds: 1,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.ease,
                  );
                },
                child: Text('top'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

For example, let's say we made an app like the one above using a ready-made widget called CustomListView.

We can control scrolling by pressing a button(Inner button) inside the CustomListView.
This is fine.

but what if, for example, we want to control the scrolling of a ListView inside a CustomListView when we press the Outer button?

---

↓For example, in the CustomListView definition, make the CustomListView receive a ScrollController:

```
class CustomListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.ctrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ScrollController ctrl;

  @override
  State<CustomListView> createState() => _CustomListViewState();
}

class _CustomListViewState extends State<CustomListView> {
  late final ScrollController ctrl;
  double position = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    ctrl = widget.ctrl;

    /*
    ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        print(ctrl.offset);
        setState((){
          position = ctrl.offset;
        });
      });
    */
  }
```

↓And in the outer MyApp declare a ScrollController and pass it to the CustomListView.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey listViewKey = GlobalKey();
  late final ScrollController ctrl;
  ...

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//in the build method of _MyAppState

            Expanded(
              child: CustomListView(
                key: listViewKey,
                ctrl: ctrl,
              ),
            ),
```

Now we can control the scrolling of the CustomListView from the outer MyApp, but for that we need to modify the CustomListView definition.

I think there are situations where we can't change the code, such as when the CustomListView is not our own.

If so, is there a way to control the CustomListView's scrolling and get the scroll position from the outer MyApp?
Does it mean that it is impossible because there is no way?

---

It just came to my mind, could NotificationListner/ScrollNotification be the solution?
Or if there is another way, please let me know.

Comment: Is `listViewKey.currentState` not working?

Comment: I wrote an answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the scrollController inside `_CustomListViewState` with the `listViewKey` that you provided to the `CustomListView` widget like this:

```
ScrollController controller = (listViewKey.currentState as _CustomListViewState).ctrl
```

You may need to remove `_` if the `_CustomListViewState` is inside another file.

If you wrote the `CustomListView` then it is best practice to accept an external scrollController. If not provided externally then you can create an instance of scrollController inside `CustomListView`.

Comment: Seems like your question is already answered.